# Locking ostream output in macro

Tags: c++, cout

I have this code for some proprietary logger:

```
#define LOG GetStream()
```

Where GetStream returns an std::ostream. User will do:

```
LOG << "text";
```

I need this to be thread safe but would like to avoid this:

```
#define END Unlock();
#define LOG Lock(); GetStream() << "text" << END;
```

Since user will need to add the "END":

```
LOG << "Text" << END;
```

Any ideas?

Remark: I handle the carriage return using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510071/mycout-automatic-endl).

Comment: why do it in a macro anyway

Comment: You could provide a wrapper logger relatively easily instead of going the ugly way with macros.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to use function-style macros, where you incorporate the locking/unlocking by using a C++ block and scoping:

```
#define LOG(output)               \
    do                            \
    {                             \
        LockingClass lock;        \
        GetStream() << output;    \
    } while (0)
```

The `LockingClass` (or whatever you want to name it) is a scoped lock, which locks the stream on construction, and unlocks it in on destruction.

Could be used like e.g.

```
LOG("hello variable is " << variable);
```

Can't use it with expressions containing comma though, the preprocessor will interpret commas as argument separator for the macro. Could probably be solved with [variadic macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro).

Comment: again, this is an alternative way. you can't do it with `<<` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Just though of this:

```
#define LOG for (int i = 0 ;i < 1 ;i++,(i == 1 ? Unlock())) LockAndGetStream()
```

Comment: Although the code looks so hideous, this does exactly what grunt asked for. +1 And then I realized its himself.

Answer (score 0):

TL;TD: you can't make the whole `x<<text<<end` work only by macros.

in order to put many expressions with a semicolon (`;`) with a macro , the only valid way is using the `do{..} while(0)` statement , you can read about it more here : [do { ... } while (0) — what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

now, all good until you want to use some operators like `<<`, then you can't use the `do{..} while(0)` costruct.

my suggestion : wrap the `std::ostream` in a class where you overload the `<<` operator. inside the overload , call `Lock` and `Unlock`.

```
struct MyLogger{
  std::ostream& operator << (Text text){
    Lock();
    stream <<text;
    Unlock();
    return stream;
  }
}
```

where `stream` is the stream you stream the text into.

now, you can create an object from this class and use regular, non-macro `<<`:

```
NyLogger Log;
Log << text;
```

Comment: I edited this, to correct for too many `;`. However, I think this is still incorrect to say that `<<` won't work with `do{ ... } while(0)`. Why do you say this? Joachim's answer works well with `do{ ... } while(0)`

Comment: he uses `<<` inside the do.. while. he doesn't take some expression with already `<<` and make it work with macro. he basically works with X(Y) macro, not X<<Y . that's my point.

Comment: Ah yes I see. The questioner wants to be able to use the "macro" as `LOG << stuff;`, but we can only implement `LOG(stuff);` within macros. Agreed. Yours is the only solution I think that allows `LOG << stuff;` (where `stuff` is of type `Text`)

Comment: May I suggest a template, so that the argument can be of any type? Just change it to `template<typename T> operator << (T&& text)`  (Or `const T&` if pre-C++11)